# "Set as start page" and index.html

Tags: asp.net

If I set page "MyPage.aspx" as the start page, do I also need an index.html file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Setting a page as a start page in Visual Studio only affects what page is loaded when you launch from the VS IDE. You'll have to configure IIS when you deploy if you want "MyPage.aspx" to be the default page that loads once your site is in production.

Answer (score 2):

No you don't need, but you need to set your start page "MyPage.aspx as startup also on IIS.

Answer (score 0):

As the above said , simply no. setting default page from IDE will automatically make it as default page. Only you have to do some settings in IIS that is from the properties of the web application, go to the tab where the default pages are displayed. Add the name of the page you have set from the VS IDE.